# Is there an equation I can use to link the length of a guitar/violin string to the sustain time of that string after being plucked?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, energy, waves, home-experiment

Sustain time: the length of time the string vibrates and the sound can be heard after being plucked.
I'm looking for a relationship between the variables in order to construct a graph for a link between the two.
The force used to pluck the instrument is constant.

Comment: This question isn't clear. Are you measuring something or do you want a theoretical equation, and what variables, intensity vs time, or something else?

Comment: I'm performing the experiment and measuring the length and sustain time, variables - length vs sustain time.

Comment: Got it. But if you're performing an experiment, then why do you need a relationship? That's what the results of the experiment are supposed to tell you. I'd suggest just start to get some data, and then plot sound amplitude vs time. (It should be something like exponential decay, but you don't really need to focus on that now). Try this for different strings, fretting, etc. Isn't this a good way to start?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the path forward. You will supply the details:

Energy leaves the vibrating string via coupling to the air (which is tiny) and via coupling to the vibrating body of the instrument (which is significant).

These energy losses appear in the equation of motion of the string as *damping terms* that "look" just like friction but which are actually due to the *radiation resistance* of the vibrating body of the instrument, as it pulls energy from the string and transforms it into air movement i.e., *sound waves*.

So you use the *damped harmonic oscillator* equation for the string which will possess a *time constant* that describes the exponential die-off of the oscillatory portion of the solution to the equation.

For long time constants, the instrument's *sustain* will be great. For short time constants, the *sustain* will be small.

Answer (score 0):

From [Mit](https://dspace.mit.edu/bitstream/handle/1721.1/36869/18-303Fall-2004/NR/rdonlyres/Mathematics/18-303Fall-2004/901E96F1-5F61-4EFC-AADD-C9352D29B241/0/probwave1solns.pdf):

The Wave Equation for a string subject to damping force $-b \frac{\partial u}{\partial t}$ per unit length is

$$\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2}=c^2 \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}-2k\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2}$$

The energy of the wave for a string of length $l$ is

$$E(t)=\frac{\rho}{2} \int^l _{0}u_t^2 +c^2 u_x^2 \space dx$$

$$\frac{dE}{dt} =-2k\rho\int^l _{0}u_t^2 \space dx$$

The energy decreases.

[The frequency of a string is related to its length](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_vibration) $L$.

$$f=\frac{1}{2L} \sqrt{\frac{T}{\mu}}$$

where $T$ is the tension and $\mu$ is the linear density.

The following is my contribution so it could very well be wrong:

Assume $u_t$ is proportional to $f$ or $u_t =qf$.

$$\frac{dE}{dt} =-2k\rho\int^L _{0} (qf)^2 \space dx =-2k\rho\int^L _{0} (q\frac{1}{2L} \sqrt{\frac{T}{\mu}})^2 \space dx=-\frac{2k\rho q^2}{4\mu} \frac{T}{L}$$

The energy decreases faster for smaller $L$.